# Laravel 5.2 : Test Uploaded File is Valid: isValid() on a non-object

Tags: php, laravel, tdd, mockery

I'm trying to test my uploaded file function. I'm mocking the UploadedFile, but I get this error from my controller:

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
>     Call to a member function isValid() on a non-object

The uploaded file (mocked UploadedFile) will be received by my controller, but I can't call any method of UploadedFile.

My controller:

```
class FileController extends Controller
{
    public function upload(Request $request)
    {
        return $request->file('file')->isValid();
    }
}
```

My test looks as follows:

```
class FileTest extends TestCase
{
    private $fileMock;

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->fileMock = Mockery::mock(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile::class,
        [
            'getClientOriginalName'      => public_path() . '/images/foo.jpg',
            'getClientOriginalExtension' => 'jpg',
            'image/jpeg',
            null,
            null,
            true
        ]);
    }

    /** @test */
    public function it_gets_an_uploaded_file()
    {
        $this->fileMock
        ->shouldReceive('isValid')
        ->once()
        ->andReturn(true);

        $this->call('POST', 'file/upload', [], [], ['file' => [$this->fileMock]]);
        $this->assertResponseOk();

    }

    public function tearDown()
    {
        Mockery::close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you print out $request->file('file') in your upload method when running the test? Is it null or an array or a mockery object?

Comment: Thanks Fredrik. It's the mockery object.

Comment: Ok, then it's very weird that you get "Call to a member function isValid() on a non-object". If you print our the Mockery object you should be able to see what methods on the object that are mocked. Can you see isValid() to be listed in this object?

Comment: The mockery object has only its own methods, such as shouldReceive(), once(), but not the methods of UploadedFile. The mock 'call' works fine, I receive a file in my controller method, but that's the mockery object with onlyits own method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `$request->file('file')` is an array. Therefore you need to change:

```
public function upload(Request $request)
{
    return $request->file('file')->isValid();
}
```

to this:

```
public function upload(Request $request)
{
    return $request->file('file')[0]->isValid(); 
}
```

in your FileController.